# Annotations in Isometric View AutoCAD 2014

Tags: drawing, isometric, autocad

[image: Drawing]

I want to set Annotations for my drawing but in isometric view it gives me the distance following the orange line when I need the length of the yellow one. Does anyone know what settings I should change to obtain desired result.

Comment: Not *really* sure AutoCAD fits into the realm of **Graphic** design.